# Deep-linking in android xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.android, deep-linking

I have a requirement where I would like my app to be opened from an email link. I tried by adding the following code in AndroidManifest file.

```
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name">
<!-- Accept chrome links -->
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="example.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/"/>
</intent-filter>
<!-- Accept adb data flag -->
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="example.com"/>
</intent-filter>
```

But it didn't work both from abd shell as well as chrome link. Below is the adb shell command I was trying.

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "http://example.com" QRcodeScanner.QRcodeScanner
```

It opened up tha app but then I was getting error:

```
QRcodeScanner.QRcodeScanner.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "QRcodeScanner.QRcodeScanner.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/QRcodeScanner.QRcodeScanner-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/QRcodeScanner.QRcodeScanner-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/QRcodeScanner.QRcodeScanner-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
```

Finally, I got an example somewhere that states to add an intent filter in the activity. So below is the code which worked for adb command:

```
   [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
          Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryBrowsable, Intent.CategoryDefault },
          DataScheme = "http",
          DataHost = "example.com",
          AutoVerify = true)]
```

But it didn't work from chrome link: `<a href=”http://example.com”>app_link</a>`

My activity is in the root folder at present but I would later be moving it to activities folder under root folder. Will it make a difference?

Also, how to retrieve data from the URL link in MainActivity?

Answer (score 1):

if your activity is under activitys folder then try,

```
<activity
android:name="activitys.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name">
```